# Is it feasible to launch spacecraft/payload by water steam generated by a nuclear blast?

Tags: launch, rockets, advanced-propulsion

[image]

The Spaceship with a concave bottom is kept on top of a hole which contains water. A nuclear blast then converts the water to steam which gives the thrust to the spaceship.

My question is that is this method feasible, if not then why?

Comment: Why heavy water instead of regular water?

Comment: This is a duplicate of any number of '[space gun](http://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=launch+gun)' questions.

Comment: Much more interesting if [cryogenic deuterium was used instead of heavy water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Mike)!

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩: A better link: [Operation Plumbbob - the Pascal B test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Plumbbob#Propulsion_of_steel_plate_cap)

Comment: The post is not about creating a thermonuclear blast with the heavy water, but steam, so why heavy water instead of plain water?

Comment: Steampunk rockets would be so cool.

Comment: Infi - "heavy water contain radiation"? What does that even mean in this context?

Answer (score 5):

First, heavy water and its steam would rather dampen the blast than amplify it. It's not how thermonuclear charges work. But that's a technicality...

If you want to deliver raw materials into space, this is semi-viable (incurring a significant loss during travel through the atmosphere as the outer surface will melt into plasma). But with proper ablators, heat shielding etc, it would be *somewhat* doable, though not easy. And there's risk of significant irradiation of the cargo.

If you want to deliver anything slightly fragile (say, more fragile than a solid block of of steel) it will shatter due to impact of the blast, the acceleration exerting force of a concentrated thermonuclear blast.

No humans, no electronics, no rocket engines, no systems or structures.

And due to lack of these it won't be able to circularize the orbit once above the atmosphere, so unless you launch it at a speed that would allow escape from Earth's gravity, it will just fall back to Earth, even if it was to cross Moon orbit on the way. Simply, any "orbit" achieved by a single, point acceleration passes through that point (approaching from the opposite side) - and since that point is on Earth surface, it means the payload will hit Earth somewhere "on the other side".

Although, as I wrote - this is semi-viable. At higher orbits the energy to change orbit (circularize) is relatively low, so if the payload was encountered by an orbital "tug" that could give it an acceleration (or some kind of propulsion was developed that would survive the nuclear blast) - yes,the payload could be brought to orbit.

Comment: So to summarise (suppose I don't want my ship to orbit)  then the main problem according to you is tremendous initial acceleration that the ship would not be able to sustain.

Comment: Your scenario is with a single explosion rather than a continuous one right ?

Comment: I disagree with the "no electronics" here--we can pack electronics into artillery shells so I wouldn't rule out electronics in this case.  I wouldn't even say "no rocket engines"--they build rocket engines that can take being fired from artillery.  The circularization burn is small enough that a solid rocket motor could do it.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: No artillery on Earth produces this kind of acceleration, by far. Tanks muzzle velocities exceed 1,700 m/s for kinetic penetrators (no electronics/explosives in these!) and here we need speeds way, way above 9000m/s (which would barely suffice without any atmospheric drag).

Comment: @Infi: this is the worst problem. The problem of atmospheric heat (unlike reentry vehicles that lose speed gradually as the atmosphere gets thicker, this one has top speed in the densest atmosphere) is tremendous, but still not as bad as the acceleration problem - most materials behave like liquids at these accelerations.

Comment: @SF. Muzzle velocity is not acceleration.  He said nothing about barrel length, with a long enough barrel you can get it down to the same acceleration.  Besides, electronics in artillery dates to WWII (yes, vacuum tubes!), I would think we could do better after 70 years of doing it.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: If the "muzzle velocity" of our payload was to be 20km/s (a plausible ballpark figure), it would take 1s to exit a 1km long barrel with 20,000m/s^2 that is over 2000g - in case some kind of cushioning was provided to distribute the acceleration evenly over that 1s. Which would be hard if we were to ride a thermonuclear blastwave which would almost surely incur higher acceleration at the moment of impact.

Comment: ...and over the 70 years we have perfected missiles which replace the huge initial acceleration with much more gentle acceleration over a longer time, allowing for more elaborate and more fragile electronics to survive the flight...

Comment: @SF. 2000g is small potatoes compared to artillery shell launch accelerations.  Anything we can do with artillery we could do with such a nuclear gun.

Comment: @SF. And in those 70 years we are turning around and looking at railguns--the prototypes of them doing 60,000g.  At railgun ranges you'll have to guide them to get a hit--they're planning to build a guidance system that can take that 60,000g.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32146/discussion-between-sf-and-loren-pechtel).